# JSON response from SpreadSheet API

Tags: shell, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have spread sheet mentioned below

```
Name    Marks
Adam    81
Mark    12
Carl    89
```

When I am using spreadsheet API as mentioned below,

> https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spread_sheet_id/values/Sheet1?key=API_key

I am getting a response as a nested list in `values` field,

```
{
"range": "Sheet1!A1:Z1000",
"majorDimension": "ROWS",
"values": [
    [
        "Name",
        "Marks"
    ],
    [
        "Adam",
        "81"
    ],
    [
        "Mark",
        "12"
    ],
    [
        "Carl",
        "89"
    ]
]
```

}

But what I do want is a proper json format in the `values` field,

```
"values": [ {"Name":"Adam", "Marks":81},
            {"Name":"Mark", "Marks":12},
            {"Name":"Carl", "Marks":89} ]
```

Is that can be done using Google Sheet API alone?

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, your expected values cannot be directly retrieved using Sheets API. In this case, it is required to convert the output values from Sheets API using a script. So, in your situation, what language do you want to achieve your goal using?

Comment: I use shell script

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I added the tags.

Comment: How can i do it in NodeJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to achieve the following conversion.

  - From

    ```
      {
         "range":"Sheet1!A1:Z1000",
         "majorDimension":"ROWS",
         "values":[
            [
               "Name",
               "Marks"
            ],
            [
               "Adam",
               "81"
            ],
            [
               "Mark",
               "12"
            ],
            [
               "Carl",
               "89"
            ]
         ]
      }
    ```
  - To

    ```
      {
         "values":[
            {
               "Name":"Adam",
               "Marks":81
            },
            {
               "Name":"Mark",
               "Marks":12
            },
            {
               "Name":"Carl",
               "Marks":89
            }
         ]
      }
    ```
- You want to achieve the above conversion using Sheets API.
- When I asked the language that you are using, you say `I use shell script`. From this, you want to achieve this using a shell script.

Unfortunately, in the current stage, your expected values cannot be directly retrieved using Sheets API. It seems that this is the current specification of the Google side. In this case, it is required to convert the output values from Sheets API using a script.

When a shell script is used for achieving your goal, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

In this script, `jq` is used. [Ref](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

```
#!/bin/sh
data='{ "range": "Sheet1!A1:Z1000", "majorDimension": "ROWS", "values": [["Name", "Marks"], ["Adam", "81"], ["Mark", "12"], ["Carl", "89"]] }'
echo ${data} | jq '.values[0][0] as $h1 | .values[0][1] as $h2 | .values[1:] | {"values": map({($h1): .[0], ($h2): .[1]})}'
```

- You can test this using https://jqplay.org/s/RSRyWj_ZLXO.

#### Note:

- As additional information, when I saw your tags in your questions, `python` is included. So, when you want to achieve this using a python script, how about the following sample script?

  ```
    import json

    data = '{ "range": "Sheet1!A1:Z1000", "majorDimension": "ROWS", "values": [["Name", "Marks"], ["Adam", "81"], ["Mark", "12"], ["Carl", "89"]] }'
    obj = json.loads(data)
    values = obj["values"]
    (h1, h2) = values[0]
    res = {"values": [{(h1): v1, (h2): v2} for (v1, v2) in values[1:]]}
    print(res)
  ```

  - When this script is run, you can obtain the value of `{'values': [{'Name': 'Adam', 'Marks': '81'}, {'Name': 'Mark', 'Marks': '12'}, {'Name': 'Carl', 'Marks': '89'}]}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
const response = `
{
"range": "Sheet1!A1:Z1000",
"majorDimension": "ROWS",
"values": [
    [
        "Name",
        "Marks"
    ],
    [
        "Adam",
        "81"
    ],
    [
        "Mark",
        "12"
    ],
    [
        "Carl",
        "89"
    ]
]
}`

function myFunction() {
  let values = []
  let json = JSON.parse(response)
  let val1 = json.values[0][0]
  let val2 = json.values[0][1]
  json.values.forEach((v, i) => {
    if (i > 0) {
      let x = {}
      x[val1] = v[0]
      x[val2] = v[1]
      values.push(x)
    }
  })
  console.log(`"values" : ` + JSON.stringify(values))
}
```

```js
const response = `
{
"range": "Sheet1!A1:Z1000",
"majorDimension": "ROWS",
"values": [
    [
        "Name",
        "Marks"
    ],
    [
        "Adam",
        "81"
    ],
    [
        "Mark",
        "12"
    ],
    [
        "Carl",
        "89"
    ]
]
}`

  let values = []
  let json = JSON.parse(response)
  let val1 = json.values[0][0]
  let val2 = json.values[0][1]
  json.values.forEach((v, i) => {
    if (i > 0) {
      let x = {}
      x[val1] = v[0]
      x[val2] = v[1]
      values.push(x)
    }
  })
  console.log(`"values" : ` + JSON.stringify(values))
```